# onmousedown IE8 not working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have created something like this

```
<textarea id='txtarea'>Dear Sir/Madam








Sincerely,

[Your Name]
</textarea><br/><input id="btn" value='Add Date' type="button"/>

<script>
var textarea=document.getElementById('txtarea'),pos=0
textarea.focus()
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=addDate
document.getElementById('btn').onmousedown=function(){return false}
function addDate(){  
textarea.innerHTML+="\n"+new Date().toUTCString()
} 
</script>
```

All of this this code works fine on all browser except IE 8 and lower... the problem is:

When the textarea is focused and user clicks Add Date button the textarea doesn't need to be deselected (`onmousedown=function(){return false}`). In IE 8 and lower it gets deselected (I think the `return false` is not working).

What to do to support IE 8 and lower.

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngdQm/1/)**

Comment: Why don't you use semicolons? I'm surprised that works at all.

Comment: @nullability , where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older IEs there's `unselectable` attribute available. By setting it `on` prevents an element having the attribute to receive the focus.

```
<input id="btn" value='Add Date' type="button" unselectable="on" />
```

I couldn't find any documentation just now, but if I can recall correctly, this attribute needs to be set wheter literally to a tag or it can be set programmatically with `setAttribute()`. Setting `unselectable` property doesn't have an effect.

---

An article about [semicolons](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). Though the article explains also, when you can omit semicolons, it's safest always use them.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works (not tested in ie)

```
document.getElementById('btn').onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```